# Looking for an alternative to unset

Tags: php, oop

I have a class with a number of properties
which is used to create a number of different objects. Depending on object specifics, some objects will not need certain class properties, so I unset them during constructor method call.

```
class maker{
public $prop1;
public $prop2;
...
public $propn;

public function __construct($item){

if($item!='first')unset(prop2);
if(!in_array($item,['third', 'fifth']))foreach(['prop3','prop6','propn'] AS $prop)unset($this->$prop);

...

}
```

The code will then need to execute depending on some of the properties set along the process.
I've put a method in place for quick check to account for an instance when there is no such property

```
public function isString($prop){
return (property_exists($this->first->$prop) && is_string($this->first->$prop));
}
```

Everything works as expected until I check a $prop which was previously unset within the constructor.

The PHP manual clearly states that unset() does not completely destroy the property of an object, but rather sets its value to NULL internally, so when property_exists() is called, it will naturally return TRUE.
Simple workaround is to just add isset() to the hasProp() method, but I was wondering whether there is a substitute method to completely remove a property from the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the definition of each instance of a class based on its data makes this long-time OO programmer cringe. (Removing a public prop is a definition change.)

Why? The point of using classes is to present a predictable definition to a user of the class. That user is the next person to work on the code. That person might be your future self, or somebody you hire when your business grows. If you need to add a feature to this code three years from now, you'll have to remember this vanishing-property stuff you propose to build, or teach the new colleague how to use it.

php offers the [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function. It's a warning-free way to tell whether an item of data has never been initialized, or has been the subject of unset(). It works on all sorts of things, including class-instance properties and array elements. It might work for you, if you establish the rule, for example, that `prop2` is only set for the `'first'` item.

If you *must* vary your class-instance definitions based on data, you might consider using [inheritance](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) or [interfaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation O.Jones.
Unfortunately, empty() method will return TRUE for boolean FALSE, so not the ideal solution.
I did consider inheritance, but the more properties, the more differences can be there and creating an extension simply to remove one parameter seems an overkill, so conditions or a switch statement looks easier to read option in my case.
Interfaces cannot have their own properties, so are no use in this case either.

Comment: The interface suggestion means: define a separate class for each data variant, and make them all implement the same interface.